# AppFabric Cache Error:The AppFabric Caching Service service terminated unexpectedly

Tags: windows-services, appfabric

I am running cluster machine in Virtual Box in domain, by default service is running under Network service , service stopped all the time with the following error in the event log.

please find the error details from error log below. any help will be great.

```
Log Name:  System
Source:  Service Control Manager
Date:   21-07-2010 16:42:07
Event ID:  7034
Task Category: None
Level:   Error
Keywords:  Classic
User:   N/A
Computer:  
Description:
The AppFabric Caching Service service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 5 time(s).
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
 <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908D1-A6D7-4695-8E1E-26931D2012F4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
 <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7034</EventID>
 <Version>0</Version>
 <Level>2</Level>
 <Task>0</Task>
 <Opcode>0</Opcode>
 <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
 <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-07-21T14:42:07.000Z" />
 <EventRecordID>13342</EventRecordID>
 <Correlation />
 <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
 <Channel>System</Channel>
 <Computer>
 <Security />
 </System>
 <EventData>
 <Data Name="param1">AppFabric Caching Service</Data>
 <Data Name="param2">5</Data>
 </EventData>
</Event>
```

thanks for the support.

kazim

Comment: Have you found the solution to this??

Comment: Added my solution as answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much information in the above error to guess what went wrong. Try to take a look at events right before this particular event (maybe there will be hint/warning about something). Another thing might be not to look only at a regular eventlog `Windows Logs` > `Application` but also at eventlog `Applications and Services Logs` > `Microsoft` > `Application Server-System Services`.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with David that there is not much one could make out of this log entry.

Another thing worth checking would be to make sure that your configuration is available to AppFabric services. May it be an xml or SQL based configuration provider, AppFabric services should be able to access it. This is the most common reason of crashing services at the load time.

You can very easily check this by running your appFabric configuration wizard.

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved]

I got the same issue. Couldn't find a definite answer anywhere. However after looking at all the configurations and connections, I figured out the root cause.

**For information**, in my case, I was using a ***SQL Configuration***.

**The issue was that** my AppFabric database was not part of a cluster and availability group which it should have been actually. Once I added it to the availability group and after it got replicated in all the SQL nodes, I re-configured app fabric on the cache servers (using configure app fabric tool) and stopped and started my cache cluster again.

This time, everything worked as expected.

Hope this helps you too!

**P.S.:** I'm not sure if the "reconfiguring app fabric using the tool" is a mandatory step. I just did it from my side. Perhaps you can try stopping and starting the cache cluster without doing this. Do let me know in case it is not mandatory so that I can update this answer accordingly.